# How to make pdf table as selectable content?

Tags: java, itext

I have to extract whole pdf content using iText. But i couldn't read the contents in table.Because table is not a selectable part in Pdf. How can I make the table content as selectable in order to extract the table content?

Comment: Hello Anjaly, I can assum that you know how to work with itext so for your question about reading table from pdf you can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276893/reading-a-table-or-cell-value-in-a-pdf-file-using-java) post. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Define: "selectable". You need to do something special to prevent "copy/paste" options. You can always "copy/paste" content by default if you create the PDF correctly. However, if you want to preserve the table structure, you need to create the PDF as a Tagged PDF. Did you create a Tagged PDF? I don't understand why your question received two up-votes because it is not a good question.

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question? Pdf parts may not be selectable for very many reasons...