# How can i get specific text from pdf using pdfbox api in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I used this code and output was the entire page text and i want the specific 
    text?
    any solutions please?

```
public class ReadingText {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:/PdfBox_Examples/new.pdf");
      PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
      PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
      String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
      System.out.println(text);
      document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `pdfStripper.getText(document);` means? 
What spesific text are you looking for? Can you provide examples on what you are getting, and examples on what you want?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you have to somehow "parse" the text string you already got by `getText` then?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what "specific text" means. An area? A table element? A page? Text with specific font? Text in specific language?

Comment: a text from specific area which is selected by users

Comment: Then try the `ExtractTextByArea.java` example in the source code download or here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/ExtractTextByArea.java?view=markup

Comment: If the comment answered your question, then I think your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276893/reading-a-table-or-cell-value-in-a-pdf-file-using-java/28295244#28295244  So you should delete yours and upvote that one (if it helps). You can also answer this question yourself, but in that case you should improve it first as explained in the comments.