# Which java library can create pdf file like this?

Tags: java, itext

I am developing an web site, and will have user to fill a form, at last will send the pdf file which look the same as the form to the user.
The pdf looks like below.
[image]

Comment: Please stop spreading incorrect information. I will edit your question. iText is Free Software under the AGPL license, an OSI-approved license. Which means that you don't have to pay for it if your own software is also AGPL. You only have to pay for a commercial license if your own software cannot be AGPL.

Answer (score 4):

There is a library called iText which can be used in Java and .NET

https://developers.itextpdf.com/downloads

https://github.com/itext/itext7

You will simply create rows, columns, tables, and style them to look like your form.

You can also take a HTML screenshot which your send to server-side and can place that in the PDF also created with iText

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

If the links don't work, there are plenty of other posts, just google and you will find something

### **Edit:**

Like `@KhaledLela` mentioned you can use iText as long as all your code is shared, else you have to buy a commercial license.

An alternative can be https://pdfbox.apache.org/ which is distributed under the Apache license.

Comment: DownVoted!!, OP asked about free solution, `iText` library is under **AGPL** as a viral license: all the software that touches an AGPL library such as iText needs to be free too. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867740/1283715)

Comment: @KhaledLela An alternative in this case might be `https://pdfbox.apache.org/`

Comment: I did and read the comments BTW, If you did please read it again with more attention. This means that anyone can use iText for free as long as the conditions for its use are met. **Copyleft**
`To know more about the conditions, you need to take a look at the license. In this case: the AGPL. This means that:

You can not distribute a closed source application that is based on iText without distributing the full source code of your own application.
You can not use iText in a web application without making the full source code of your web application available through that web application`

Comment: how abut JasperReports  library?

Comment: I have edited your answer. iText Software no longer uses SourceForge, the source code is on GitHub.

Comment: @KhaledLela iText is Free as in Free Speech. You can look at the source code. It is also free as in free beer, provided your own software is also Free as in Free Speech. OP did not specify which type of free they meant.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thanks for your clarification about `iText`, And that is what i exactly mentioned above that `iText` is under **AGPL**, And i know the meaning of license you are free to use as far your software is also free.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse But i think OP specify when he said that he develop a website and asking about free tool that means that his website is closed source and not public, This is my expectation that may be wrong!.

Comment: I do not assume to know anything about what the OP has intended but hasn't written. I only reply to what was written. As for websites: it is perfectly possible for a website to have a link to the git repository with the source code of said website.